# Apply JDK 8 Consumer on String

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a question regarding Java 8. Here is my source code:

```
final Consumer<String> d = e -> System.out.println(e);
final Function<String, String> upper = x -> x.toUpperCase();
final Function<String, String> lower = x -> x.toLowerCase();

new Thread(() -> d.accept(upper.apply("hello 1"))).run();
new Thread(() -> d.accept(lower.apply("hello 2"))).run();
```

This works quite well and produces following output:

```
HELLO 1
hello 2
```

My question is now if the syntax above `d.accept` and `upper.apply` is the only possible one or if there is some more "java 8 lambda" style we could write the last two lines.

Comment: These lambdas are all ideal candidates for using _method references_ instead: System.out::println, String::toUpperCase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before saying anything about about lambda expressions or functional interfaces, we have to talk about your really problematic mistake: *you are calling* `run()` *on a thread!* If you want to start a new thread, you have to call `start()` on the `Thread` instance, if you want to run the code sequentially, don’t create a `Thread` (but just a `Runnable`).

That said, there are some `default` method on the functional interfaces of Java 8 for combining functions, e.g. you can chain two `Function`s via [`Function.andThen(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) but the available combinations are far away from being complete.

If a certain combining task repeats in your application, you may consider creating utility methods:

```
public static <T> Runnable bind(T value, Consumer<T> c) {
    return ()->c.accept(value);
}
public static <T,U> Consumer<U> compose(Function<U,T> f, Consumer<? super T> c) {
    return u->c.accept(f.apply(u));
}
```

```
new Thread(bind("Hello 1", compose(upper, d))).start();
new Thread(bind("Hello 2", compose(lower, d))).start();
```

But these three parts look more like a task for the stream API:

```
Stream.of("Hello 1").map(upper).forEach(d);
Stream.of("Hello 2").map(lower).forEach(d);
```

I left the creation of the new thread out here, as it hasn’t any benefit anyway.

If you really want parallel processing, you can do it on a per-character basis:

```
"Hello 1".chars().parallel()
  .map(Character::toUpperCase).forEachOrdered(c->System.out.print((char)c));
```

but there still won’t be any benefit given the simplicity of the task and the fixed overhead of the parallel processing.

Comment: Regarding the parallel processing: the default `chars()` implementation in JDK8 is really bad. Unlikely you will get the noticeable speedup even for the long strings. It's much better in JDK9.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: I know that but I didn’t want to go too deep into the details. After all, even with the better splitting support of Java 9, the task of this question won’t benefit from parallel execution. I doubt that there can ever be a `String` being long enough that a simple `toUpperCase` transformation can benefit from parallel execution. By the way, the Java 8 API has a way to overcome this limitation: use `CharBuffer.wrap(string).chars()` instead of `string.chars()`…

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot. You are abolutely right with Thread.run. This was just an example and has noting to do with the lambdas.

Comment: @Holger: wow, did not know about `CharBuffer` hack. Probably I should use it in my `IntStreamEx.ofChars`.

Comment: @Holger: it [seems that](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/461e663e696ad9f15447) for 1,000,000 chars String and using JDK9 `chars()` or `CharBuffer.wrap(str)` the parallel version can be faster than simple `String.toUpperCase()` (tested on quad-core machine).

Answer (score 5):

You can also write like this:

```
    new Thread(() -> Stream.of("hello 1").map(upper).forEach(d)).run();
    new Thread(() -> Stream.of("hello 1").map(lower).forEach(d)).run();
```

Or more directlry:

```
    new Thread(() -> Stream.of("hello 1").map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println)).run();
    new Thread(() -> Stream.of("hello 1").map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(System.out::println)).run();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the only possible syntax. Actually when you use the lambda you don't even know whether it's actually lambda or just a plain old implementation of given interface (via anonymous class or even normal class). So you have to use functional interface as any other Java interface: call its method explicitly.